# iOS determining how many sub-UIViews it would Overlapped

Tags: ios

Let's say if 2 small UIViews has been added to the view.
Then 3rd UIView would be added on top, How do I determine if 3rd UIView would overlapped the first 2 UIViews?

Comment: How about how many sub UIViews underneath it would overlapped? Any helper function that would return an integer indicates how many UIViews it would overlapped?

Comment: There isn't one. You'll have to cycle through the subviews and increment a count yourself every time one is detected.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a method on your UIView subclass (the container) that calculated this for you pretty easily:

```
-(NSArray*)getOverlappingViewsForSubview:(UIView*)mySubview {
    NSMutableArray* overlappedSubviews = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

    for(UIView* someSubview in self.subviews) {
        if(CGRectIntersectsRect(mySubview.frame, someSubview.frame)) {
            [overlappedSubviews addObject:someSubview];
        }
    }

    return overlappedSubviews;
}
```

Something like that should work -- you can call count on the result of that method if you only need to know how many views intersected (or rewrite the method to return a count instead of an array of the intersected views).